# Edit remote reference in Git Config

Tags: git, gerrit, simple-git

I work with Gerritt and need some help in automating a manual step in our code check in process. Here is the background. When I clony my repo afresh, here is what I see in my Git config (inside .git folder).

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://user@git.some.server.corp/contentpipeline.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

We make the following change manually in the git config. (Ref 2nd line)

```
[remote "origin"]
    push = +refs/heads/MYBRANCH:refs/for/MYBRANCH
    url = https://user@git.some.server.corp/contentpipeline.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

The line with push is added so that the change is not directly pushed to MYBRANCH but is treated as 'Push for Review'.

I have 2 questions:

1. Can this manual addition be automated using a git CLI command.
2. We are using a NOde JS framework simple-git (https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-git?activeTab=readme) to automate this process. Can this be done using simple-git as well.

Thanks a lot,
Prabal

Comment: Try `push = +refs/heads/*:refs/for/*`.

Comment: Sounds like the kind of stuff that `sed` is used for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any setting in git config can be added using `git config [path.to.setting] [value]`.

In your case:

```
git config remote.origin.push +refs/heads/MYBRANCH:refs/for/MYBRANCH
```

Check [`git help config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for all the nitty gritty details of how to edit your configuration.

`simple-git` is just a wrapper on top of `git` command line tool, so yes, you can run the exact same command using `simple-git` -- I will let you refer to the documentation to find out how.

---

for the sake of illustration:

```
# after running:
git config foo.bar.baz Hello

# I get:
cat .git/config | tail -2
# [foo "bar"]
#   baz = Hello
```

Also, as stated in the comments, if you want to set a refspec that works for all branches (not just `MYBRANCH`), you can use :

```
git config remote.origin.push "+refs/heads/*:refs/for/*"
```

Comment: Thanks @LeGEC. it was indeed the right answer and have accepted it as well